# How to select checkbox in database mysqli table in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

**How to select checkbox in database mysqli
what should i write in checkbox value
please kindly help
i also implode function which convert array to string
 did not find values for checkbox values to print. .....
Also check the output on PICTURE...
**

[OUTPUT PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBxi0.jpg)

```
        <?php
        while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
        {
         ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fetch["tableno"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetch["customerid"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetch["item"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetch["money"]?></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:del_tableno(<?php echo $fetch["tableno"];?>)"><button>Delete</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="update.php?tableno=<?php echo $fetch["tableno"]; ?>"/><button>Update</button></td>

        <td><form method="POST">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="???">
            <input type="submit" name="sub1" value="Button for Checkbox">

            </td> </form>
        </tr>

        <?php

        }?>


    </table>

        <p style="font-size:30px">The Customer has TO Selected these Items from Menu List
    and therefore submitted to<br> Kitchener to Make the Food and
    then waiter will serve the Food to Customer.</p>
        </body>

    </html>
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['sub1']))
      {
      $chk=implode(',', $_POST['chk']);
       echo "<br>Customer has  selected the following checkbox Item to be Prepared and Eat the Food:<br/>";

        echo "<br/>".$chk."<br><br/><br/><br/><br/>";

          }  

          ?>
```

Comment: it represent the value of that particular checkbox. I would suggest to go through some tutorial about checkbox

Comment: Why do you have `form` tag for each checkbox?

Comment: Your html structure is not in right format. Form tag is opening inside table tag but your are closing table tag before closing form tag. please correct the html format then try.

Comment: i put form tag for the working of Sub1 and $chk in isset to get working

Comment: please look for the problem at input tag of checkbox where i will print all the checkbox values ...... What i will write in  VALUE="????" of checkbox ?????

Comment: @ETrending What value do you want the checkbox to have (the `chk` field in the `$_POST` array), when it is checked by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is the value of a checkbox can be concatenated with all data and after submitting, check for selected check boxes with for each loop and print all the selected rows. Like below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo "<td>".$fetch["tableno"]."</td><td>".$fetch["customerid"]."</td><td>".$fetch["item"]."</td><td>".$fetch["money"]."</td>"; ?>">
```

And after posting use this :

```
if(isset($_POST['sub1'])) // check the submitted form and print the values
   {
     echo "Below Customers have placed orders:<br/>";
     echo "<table>";
     foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $value) {
      echo "<tr>".$value."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

}
```

Comment: thanks the code works fine @Sitepose ..... A  little upgrade, When i select the row's in a checkbox, it should gave me a output in a Table (rows and cols)...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In you form, method to insert multiple checkboxes

```
<form method="POST" action="test2.php">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="InputText1">InputText1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="InputText2">InputText2<br>
        <input type="submit" name="sub1">
</form>


if(isset($_POST['sub1'])) // check the submitted form and print the values
   {
     echo "You selected the following checkbox:<br/>";
     foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $value) {
      echo $value."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: i have a  sql table form connected with sql database, in which when i select the desired row(checkbox); the output will be that desired row ....

Comment: Somewhat i figure it out .... My coding has been changed and i Updated in the Question, Still didn't find coding of Value in Checkbox???